Почему через раз работает Pjax в Yii2?
Всем привет. PJAX в форме работает через раз. Двойные запросы через раз (не ajax). Из-за этого страница перегружается. Цель - изменить значение в Select2 и подгрузить данные рядом в форме.
Контроллер:
public function actionGetExistedList()
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $id = (int)Yii::$app->request->post('id');
        $models = Category::find()->where(['parent_category_id' => $id])->orderBy(['order' => SORT_ASC])->all();

        if (empty($models)) {
            return '';
        }

        return $this->renderAjax('_existed_list', [
            'models' => $models,
        ]);
    }
}

_existed_list:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

/** @var Category[] $models */

use app\modules\admin\models\Category;

?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach ($models as $model): ?>
        <li><?= $model->name ?> - <?= $model->order ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>


_form:
<div class="col">
    <?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false, 'enableReplaceState' => false, 'id' => 'existed_list', 'timeout' => false]); ?>
    <!-- Render the attribute dropdown -->
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>

То есть, это действие "создание новой сущности", где в форме я хочу при выборе Select2 сделать обновление соседнего блока.
